# How to handle errors in Node.js/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to catch errors instead of throwing them. I attempted try/catch but realised that didn't work so im at a bit of a loose end. The two errors are mongodb related, however i think node/express errors are still thrown.

```
app.get( "/test/:lastName", function ( reqt, resp ) {
  var driverName = reqt.params.lastName
  mongoClient.connect( "mongodb://localhost/enteprise",
  function( err, db ) {
  if ( err ) {
    console.error("1 mess " + err)
  }
  var database = db.db( "enteprise" )
  var collection = database.collection( "driversCol" )

  collection.findOne( { lastName : driverName },

  function( err, res ) {
    if ( err ) {
        console.error("2 mess " + err)
    }
    resp.json( res.rate )
    db.close()
    })
  })
})
```

**CASES**

if I `curl -X GET localhost:3000/test/Owen` then '43' should be returned as thats the rate.

currently if i `curl -X GET localhost:3000/test/Cressey` it throws a type error as its not in the database.

How do I catch errors given the above code and example?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the code above to use promises like `then` and `catch` instead of the current system above of callbacks?

Comment: Whatever can handle errors instead of doing what it is doing now of throwing them

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: And also what version of node.js?

Comment: node v8.9.4, mongo v3.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you should use `next()` to send back the errors you are getting in your callbacks:

```
app.get( "/test/:lastName", function ( req, resp, next ) {
  // some code...
    if ( err ) {
      return next("1 mess " + err)
    }
```

About the TypeError, it's happening because you are getting `undefined` from MongoDB when there's not any result, but that's not an error so it will not enter the `if`. You should check the existence of objects in these cases, for example:

```
resp.json( res && res.rate || {} )
```

[Here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param) you have another example about how to handle error in these cases:

```
app.param('user', function(req, res, next, id) {

  // try to get the user details from the User model and attach it to the request object
  User.find(id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else if (user) {
      req.user = user;
      next();
    } else {
      next(new Error('failed to load user'));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you give any examples where mongo would throw an error?

Comment: Some of them: Not passing correct parameters/using a bad syntax. Internal errors such as a connection error. Trying to insert a document with a unique id (like the `_id` field) that already exists :)

Comment: `res && res.rate || {}` I can't work out the logic of this, but it works.  Could you explain please? Also which library provides User?

Comment: First `res && res.rate` is checking if `res` exists, in case it does it will try to get `res.rate` (here we are evading the TypeError). Then `|| {}` is just returning an empty object as a default value just in case `res` or `res.rate` was a falsy value (e.g. undefined).

Comment: the logic using && or || is call short circuit http://codetonics.com/javascript/short-circuit-evaluation/  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB will return an empty object if the requested query cannot be found. So you need to consider how to handle those responses, as Antonio Val posits in his answer.

However, errors can be handled differently than using `next()`, such as passing the `resp` to a function for handling errors that calls `resp.json()` with an error object or other custom message and adding a statusCode so that the callee of the endpoint can also handle errors.

For instance, change wherever you call this:

```
if ( err ) {
    console.error("1 mess " + err)
}
```

To this:

```
if ( err ) {
    console.error("1 mess " + err)
    handleErrors(resp, err)
}
```

Then create the function `handleErrors()`:

```
function handleErrors(resp, err) {
    // its up to you how you might parse the types of errors and give them codes,
    // you can do that inside the function 
    // or even pass a code to the function based on where it is called.

    resp.statusCode = 503;
    const error = new Error(err);
    resp.send({error})
}
```